# How to extract specific version to a separate path?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, version-control, source-control-explorer

I want to extract a specific version of my full solution out of TFS with the Source Control Explorer, but to a separate path.

There is the option "Get Specific Version", but this seems to overwrite my current working directory.

Isn't there an option which allows just to extract a specific version and save it to some separate path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create a new workspace to map to another folder and get the specific version into this workspace. This will also allow you to switch between these two folders from Source Control Explorer easily.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think to achieve this is to do the following:

1. Rename the root of the current source tree. ("Source.Current").
2. Do the "Get Specific Version".
3. Rename the root of this source tree. ("Source.Specific Version").
4. Rename the current source tree back to it's original name ("Source").

Somewhat laborious and potentially error prone, but it could be automated with scripting.

It would be safer to do the "Get Specific Version" onto a new machine (either real or virtual) so that you don't have to touch your current working folder.

Comment: Thanks. hmm ok, but that sounds laborious and could lead to mistakes ... I think I will do it reverse, how about  that: 1) Save a copy of my current working directory 2) get the specific version  3) Save a copy of that version, too 4) Finally swap the saved directory back . ---- What do you think ?

Comment: @SQLGeorge - That would work, but the rename saves three copy operations so is a lot quicker.

Comment: See the other answer - it is possible!

Comment: @SQLGeorge - of course! I should have thought of that.